# Twitter Bootstrap Broken Dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have had a website running bootstrap for quite a while now (since 2.2 ish). I recently have been trying to patch up the page after noticing that the drop-down bar was no longer functional. This was odd as it had been tested before and no issues arised approximately a year ago.

I have tried swapping out parts of the HTML with some of the newer bootstrap examples for the past few hours, but I can't appear to get the drop-down to work anymore.

For debugging, I have isolated the problem to its simplest case with the HTML below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>


    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="brand">Test</div>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>


            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas about what I might be missing would be very much appreciated. I believe it might be a mismatch between the versions of Bootstrap that are causing this issue. However, I am trying to refactor as little HTML as possible to get the dropdown working as I am no longer familiar with this older code.

Ultimately, I'm trying to fix this bug without migrating from 2.2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where it is in your javascript file, but you need to give the `li` a class "open". When the `li` has the class "open" then it will show the dropdown menu. So u might want to add a script something like:

```
$('.dropdown a').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Or you can change the `click` into a `hover`. Your choice.

**UPDATE**

```
$('html').on('click', function () {
    $('.dropdown.open').removeClass('open');
});
$('.dropdown a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Thank you :), that will fix the issue. However, my JS is quite rusty. How would I modify the code such that the drop down will disappear after clicking anywhere on the screen and not just the button.

Comment: now you can close it outside click. And mark the answer as correct pls